# Missing add comment link/button?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Is the add comment feature not always available? Why?

See attached example from:

- [My Crystal Report is not getting refreshed while passing parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676448/my-crystal-report-is-not-getting-refreshed-while-passing-parameter)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 50 rep to be [able to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). In the screenshot, you have 43 rep. Hence the link isn't visible.

Comment: Brilliant- thanks. I think I got confused as I can comment on my own questions and answers :)

Comment: @LeeTickett yes, you can comment on your own questions regardless of rep ;)